# VSTS release definition in reactjs

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[Click here to know about the build definition i created for the rectjs projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn3qo.png)

I have learned about the build definition through errors and trials
But, I have zero idea on release definition.I thought of creating nodejs as my backend application for my react project.It would be helpful for me and others,if anyone was able to provide a release definition example for the react+nodejs project.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create a Node.js and React app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/nodejs/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx)
2. [Build your Node.js app with Gulp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/nodejs/build-gulp?view=vsts&tabs=gitvsts%2Cweb%2Cdeploy-windows)
3. [Continuously deploy (CD) your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/archive/apps/nodejs/nodejs-to-azure?view=tfs-2017#continuously-deploy-cd-your-app)

To deploy React App project with VSTS Build and Release, you can reference below articles:

- [Deploying a Create React App project to Azure with VSTS Build and
  Release](https://sethreid.co.nz/deploying-create-react-app-project-azure-vsts-build-release/)
- [Configure CI/CD for Node.js app in Microsoft VSTS](https://elevate-org.com/2018/01/19/configure-ci-cd-for-node-js-app-in-microsoft-vsts/)
- [React + Webpack inside VSTS](https://hackernoon.com/react-webpack-inside-vsts-d6b1853f1a82)

Comment: sorry for the late reply.Able to develop static files and use the vsts build and release definition.But,I am not sure  about the react+nodejs application @andyLiMSFT

Comment: @ramakrishnar Have you check the links mentioned above? You can have a try for that follow the instructions mentioned in the linked articles.